PowerShell error: Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
very new to PS. I have tried RTFM but I go off in so many tangents. I'm grateful for ideas, pointers etc.
I have four desktop shortcuts, each closely related. I thought I know i'd run a DoS batch file to do them one after the other; that led me to loading up the PS ISE(x86).
Now I have a batch file that calls the PS1. but the script fails.
the code is:
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05\fldigi.exe" --config-dir "C:\Users\sktho\fldigi-configs\fldigiIC7300"

This results in the following  [is it perhaps the double dash --config ]
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\sktho\fldigi-configs\fldigiIC7300'.
At line:1 char:2
+  Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05\fldigi.exe"  ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I found this and others
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Add-DistributionGroupMember
text
but to be honest I don't understand, I have tried many permutations of  quote '   ' "  " and
dashes
 The Desktop Shortcut lnk works fine with 
Target: `"C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05\fldigi.exe" --config-dir "C:\Users\sktho\fldigi-configs\fldigiIC7300"`
Start in: `"C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05"`


How about using the parameter -ArgumentList ? You may (re-)read the help topic for Start-Process

Single quoting the argumentlist might work.  Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05\fldigi.exe" '--config-dir "C:\Users\sktho\fldigi-configs\fldigiIC7300"'

Thanks Olaf it gave me lots of ideas but, I'm 68 and nothing much sticks in my non-programming head. I'll re-read a few times thanks.

js2010 et.al. -- So as I said, excuse coming up - I'm 68 -- I moved the files which is what the error was telling me, if I had only read it. THANK YOU for the assistance anyway. Now where did I put my keys? :)  P.S. js2010 I'm using your single quoted version with the correct path.

The solution to your problem would be using the Start-process -Argumentist parameter separated by commas:
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Fldigi-4.2.05\fldigi.exe" -ArgumentList "--config-dir","C:\Users\sktho\fldigi-configs\fldigiIC7300"


Thanks, yes it too works, it just needed the correct file path..... My Brain hurts

The argumentlist works with or without the commas.
